# Meteor-how to use the blog_posts collection independent of the helpers provided by the package

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using ryw:blog package for one of my applications. I know how to use the provided helpers like:

```
{{> blogIndex}}
```

and

```
{{> blogShow}}
```

But now I want to use the collection of blog posts independently of these helpers. For example, I want to show only these posts where the tag is "meteor". I am trying to do it with a helper and

```
Blog_posts.find({tags: "meteor"})
```

But it does not work. I think that I make a mistake on the name of the collections on the client side. If you have an idea how to find that name or how to do the whole solution....

Comment: Can you provide some code? http://meteorpad.com

Comment: Template.posts.helpers({
  current_tag:function(){
    var posts = Blog_posts.find({tags:"meteor"});
    return posts;
  }
})
//and then {{#each}} in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the source code on GitHub, it seems like it is `Blog.Post.find({});`

https://github.com/meteor-blog/meteor-blog/blob/master/server/publications.coffee

Comment: Thank you, when I try Blog.Post.find({}).fetch() it actually returns the post objects.